# SpringBoot Jpa repository : Cast as Date in jpql

Tags: jpa, jpql

I have a query as follows:

```
@Query("select distinct i from Invoice as i where i.entityId = :entityId and CAST(i.invoiceDate AS DATE) between :start and :end")
    List<Invoice> findByEntityIdAndInvoiceDateBetween(@Param("entityId") String entityId, @Param("start") Date start, @Param("end") Date end);
```

which does not work of course, because the `CAST( ... AS DATE)` is not working.

the date is as follows in the `Invoice` class :

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
private Date invoiceDate;
```

So imagine we have an invoice in DB with a `invoiceDate` like "2018-01-02 12:00:00"

and we get a call such as :
`findByEntityIdAndInvoiceDateBetween( someId, 2018-01-01, 2018-01-02)`

this query won't return the invoice in the database, because jpa generated query uses `"2018-01-02 00:00:00"`

To overcome this, I would like to ignore the time in the `invoiceDate` during the JPA lookup.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: "is not working" ? I wonder what it is doing, maybe by looking in the LOG at what SQL is invoked ...

Comment: I guess that you must have a temporal attribute in your Invoice class. Perhaps if you use the java.util.Date as the type and use the '@Temporal' annotation with either value of TemporalType.DATE or TemporalType.TIMESTAMP you may get rid of the cast in the query.

Comment: Thanks ! @DN1 Cast as Date is not recognized.

Comment: Thanks @garfield.  currently we have temporal.timestamp and maybe using temporal.date would have worked, but changing the field is not an option. And as it is, the time portion of the date is taken into account, it does not work as it is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CAST(XXX AS LocalDate)`

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best solution is use `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` in attribute definition so you never have to worry, because the truncation is performed automatically, even for the query parameters.

In any case, you can perform truncation punctually in the query, like this:

```
@Query("select distinct i from Invoice as i where i.entityId = :entityId and function('trunc', i.invoiceDate) between :start and :end")
```

And performing mannualy trunc parameters:

```
Date truncStart = DateUtils.truncate(start, Calendar.DATE);
Date truncEnd = DateUtils.truncate(end, Calendar.DATE);
```

*org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;

Answer (score 0):

## Ignore Time in the invoiceDate

If you want to ignore the timestamp (you should delete your column first), you can change the type of **TemporalType** to **Date**

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.Date)
private Date invoiceDate;
```

but if you just want to get the value of invoiceDate without time, you can use **SimpleDateFormat** to parse date value to a string

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
sdf.format(getInvoiceDate());
```

Comment: i think i couldnT explain well.. i ll update the post